# SagePay encryption error

Tags: encryption, aes, opayo

I'm trying to integrate a classic asp site into SagePay 3.00 and cannot get past the Status Detail: 5080 : Form transaction registration failed error.
I've been checking my encryption (using the Sage adapted rijndael.asp files) using the example Sage provide and I get a slightly different output i.e. about the first 25% of my output matches Sage's example. Unsure where to go from here unless anyone can suggest a better or more reliable way of generating the encrypted file.

The text I'm encrypting (when not comparing to SagePay's test data) is:

```
spCryptTxt  = "VendorTxCode="& datediff("s",DateValue("September 11, 1963"),now()) & "-" & session("****SessionId") & "&Amount=" & formatNumber(rs("totalCost"),2)_
                                                & "&Currency=GBP"_
                                                & "&Description=***Conferenceregistration"_
                                                & "&CustomerName=" & rs("firstname") & rs("surname")_
                                                & "&CustomerEMail=" & rs("email")_
                                                & "&BillingSurname=" & rs("surname")_
                                                & "&BillingFirstnames=" & rs("firstname")_
                                                & "&BillingAddress1=" & rs("contactAddress1")_
                                                & "&BillingCity=" & rs("contactCity")_
                                                & "&BillingPostCode=" & rs("contactPostcode")_
                                                & "&BillingCountry=GB"_
                                                & "&DeliveryFirstnames=" & rs("firstname")_
                                                & "&DeliverySurname=" & rs("surname")_
                                                & "&DeliveryAddress1=" & rs("contactAddress1")_
                                                & "&DeliveryCity=" & rs("contactCity")_
                                                & "&DeliveryPostCode=" & rs("contactPostcode")_
                                                & "&DeliveryCountry=GB"_
                                                & "&SuccessURL=http://www.*****.com/****/success.asp"_
                                                & "&FailureURL=http://www.*****.com/****//failure.asp"
```

and this always gives the 5080 error.
Help!

Comment: What is the value of `spCryptTxt` then? That's what is important here.

Comment: Sorry - mean't to post the actual txt:

 value="VendorTxCode=1680647122-929896259&Amount=172.00&Currency=GBP&Description=****Conferenceregistration&CustomerName=robt&CustomerEMail=rob@****.com&BillingSurname=tay**n&BillingFirstnames=rob&BillingAddress1=****re&BillingCity=Bewdley&BillingPostCode=D****Y&BillingCountry=GB&DeliveryFirstnames=rob&DeliverySurname=ta*****n&DeliveryAddress1=****e&DeliveryCity=Bewdley&DeliveryPostCode=D****Y&DeliveryCountry=GB&SuccessURL=http://www.****.com/success.asp&FailureURL=http://www.****.com/failure.asp"

Comment: Edit your question, don't put it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Look in My Sage Pay, under Transactions > Invalid. Instead of the generic 5080 error, it should give you a more informative error code.